# Qual melhor banco de dados para Python 3?

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, python-3.x

Sou iniciante e no futuro pretendo fazer um sistema de gerenciamento para pequenas empresas. Um sistema local, qual seria o melhor banco de dados aprender para fazer esse tipo de software em Python 3?

Comment: Não há melhor, depende do que precisa e qual atende suas necessidades, mas comece com o SQLite3, que já possui uma biblioteca nativa no Python.

Comment: Depende da arquitetura de sua aplicação. Você pretende ter uma máquina servidora de banco de dados ou pretende embutir o banco de dados em sua aplicação? A esmagadora maioria, senão a totalidade, dos SGBD podem ser instalados e funcionar em uma máquina servidora. Se for do tipo embedded uma das possibilidades é o SQLite já sugerido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pergunta provavelmente vai ser fechada por que não está diretamente ligada a programação, e toda pergunta relacionad a "qual o melhor..." envolve critérios subjetivos.

No entanto, tem uma resposta que vale a pena deixar aqui: 
Em Python e outras linguagens de muito alto nível, é pouco usual se ter, em código que vai realmente para produção, ainda que em aplicações simples, uma dependência direto do banco de dados - o mais comum é ter uma camada intermediária que expõe os dados do banco de dados como objetos no programa (um ORM - "Objetc Relational Manager"). O ORM, por sua vez, abstrai todas as operações com o banco, e dá suporte a vários bancos de dados - todos os mais conhecidos, com certeza - e o seu programa vai funcionar do mesmo jeito, independente do banco que há por detrás - é só mudar a configuração de conexão e o mesmo código, escrito fazendo uso do ORM, funciona com qualquer banco.

Ai, é comum se usar o sqlite, que vem junto com o Python, para desenvolvimento, e, no ambiente de produção, se configurar algum outro banco. Mas nada impede que você use de cara um banco com um servidor independente já para desenvolver.

O ORM mais usado em Python, possivelmente o mais completo é o [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/). Sugiro que você estude ele, a não ser que o seu projeto vá ser usando o Django, que tem um ORM próprio que é muito mais conveniente dentro de projetos Django mesmo.

Answer (score -1):

Recomendaria o ProstgreSQL, porem O MySQL é o mais utilizado no desenvolvimento de aplicações onde a velocidade é importante (porém isto tem mudado com versões mais recentes do PostgreSQL), enquanto que o PostgreSQL se destaca por ser mais robusto e possuir muito mais recursos que o MySQL.

Comment: Sinto dizer, mas de tantos links na internet pegou um material meio "sofrido", para dizer de uma maneira educada. Fica a sugestão de [edit] a resposta trazendo dados com base técnica, sustentados por material de qualidade e atual.